# Excel, count first instance of a series of consective characters in a string

Tags: excel, charactercount

So I have a string that looks like this:

99999999999999999999999999999FFFFFFFFFFF9FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF99999^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^C

I am trying to count the length of the first instance of a series of a given consecutive character.

Examples:

"9" as the given char, it should count that first set of 9's and return 30.

"F" as the given char, it should return 11, for the first set of consecutive "F"s that begins after the 30 "9"s.

I"m doing this in Excel, so a formula/VBA solution is ideal.  I can translate any code into VBA if necessary though.  I feel like this has a Reg-Ex solution but I'm the Jon Snow of Reg-Ex, I know nothing.

Thanks in advance for any insights/advice.

Answer (score 2):

I will just put this here for posterity:

```
=IF(SUBSTITUTE(MID($A$1,FIND(A2,$A$1),LEN($A$1)),A2,"")="",LEN($A$1)+1,FIND(MID(SUBSTITUTE(MID($A$1,FIND(A2,$A$1),LEN($A$1)),A2,""),1,1),$A$1,FIND(A2,$A$1)))-FIND(A2,$A$1)
```

This will count the first grouping of the desired input:

[image]

Comment: I'll have to sit and think through your formula, nice job!  How'd you get to that, done something similar in the past or just tinkering until you got it?

Comment: I kept throwing things at the wall till I got what I wanted. @BruceWayne

Comment: That's my favorite method! Cheers Scott!

Answer (score 2):

And here is a REGEX solution.  Note that we have to *escape* the metacharacters.

```
Option Explicit
Function LenFirstInstance(findCHAR As String, searchSTRING As String)
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .ignorecase = False
    .Pattern = Left(findCHAR, 1) & "+"
    If .Pattern Like "[\^$.|?*+()[{]*" Then _
        .Pattern = "\" & .Pattern
    If .Test(searchSTRING) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(searchSTRING)
        LenFirstInstance = MC(0).Length
    End If
End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help? I tried it with your sample data and it seemed to work.

```
Function number_Appearances(ByVal myText As String, ByVal myRng As Range)
Dim cel As Range
Dim txtFound As Boolean
Dim celText$

Dim findText$
findText = myText

Set cel = myRng
celText = cel.Text

Dim celLen&
celLen = Len(celText)

txtFound = True

Dim i&, k&
Dim iChar$
For i = 1 To celLen
    iChar = Mid(celText, i, 1)
    If iChar = findText And txtFound = True Then
        k = k + 1
    ElseIf k > 0 And iChar <> findText Then
        txtFound = False
    End If
Next i

Debug.Print "Found " & k & " " & findText & "'s"
number_Appearances = k
End Function
```

But I started this before thinking of a formula. @ScottCraner's suggestion is preferable, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I got off my lazy bum and wrote VBA to solve.  Thank you Scott and Bruce.  And yes it was 29, not 30.  Thank you again.

```
Public Function count_first_instance_of_consecutive_chars(the_char, the_string)
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim iter As Long
    Dim is_a_match As Boolean

    is_a_match = False

    If the_char <> vbNullString And the_string <> vbNullString Then
        For iter = 1 To Len(the_string)
            If Mid(the_string, iter, 1) = the_char Then
                If is_a_match = True Then
                    counter = counter + 1
                ElseIf is_a_match = False Then
                    is_a_match = True
                    counter = 1
                End If
            Else
                If is_a_match = True Then
                    count_first_instance_of_consecutive_chars = counter
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next iter
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: If I may - next time you do this, let us know in your OP that you're working on code, instead of asking a question then working on it, and (seemingly) solving it. And, in that case, why ask the question? Why not try to write some code first, then ask SO - instead of asking SO and then doing the work...?